# Source tree is ignoring anything in my public folder

Tags: git

Im running a laravel application and trying to push my code up to bitbucket.

For some reason source tree is ignoring all file changes inside my public directory. My gitignore file looks like this :

```
/vendor
/node_modules
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
```

If you need any more information please leave a comment and I will update my question.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you didn't run a `git add`

Comment: But i didnt run that for any other files either

Comment: other files were already added

Comment: Do you want to ignore complete vendor folder ? and one more thing, have you made any changes in `.gitignore` ?

Comment: Besides .gitignore, please check .git/info/exclude and `git config --get core.excludesFile`.